# Compare unique values in one column but not the other Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way to find values in one column but not in another column?

df1:

```
col1  col2
A     5
B     7
C     8
D     10
```

df2:

```
col3  col4
C     5
D     8
E     10
F     9
```

How can I find the unique values in `df1.col1` but not `df2.col3`?

Expected output: `A, B`

and values in `df2.col3` but not in `df1.col1`?

Expected output: `E,F`

Comment: Use `isin`. `df1.col1[~df1.col1.isin(df2.col3)].unique()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `set.difference()`

```py
res = list(set(df1['col1']).difference(df2['col3']))
```

```
print(res)

['B', 'A']
```